# PGFPLOTS boxplot data from inline file

Tags: tables, pgfplots, labels, boxplot

I have The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
%\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
miles
1
2
1
5
4
10
7
10
9
8
9
9
%\end{filecontents}
}\mytable

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable}
\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y=1.5cm,ymax=2] 
\addplot+[boxplot] table[ y index=0, row sep=newline ]{\mytable}

%\addplot+[boxplot] table[row sep=\\,y index=0]{ 
%data\\ 1\\2\\1\\5\\4\\10\\ 7\\10\\9\\8\\9\\9\\ } 
%[above] 
%node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{lower whisker},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}} 
%node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{lower quartile},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower quartile}}} 
%node[left] at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{median},0.5) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}} 
%node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{upper quartile},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper quartile}}} 
%node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{upper whisker},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}} ; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiling this yields:

```
  ! File ended while scanning use of \pgfplots@addplotimpl@table@fromfile.
```

How does one implement an inline data table that boxplot can handle?
Also, how about the labels that I commented out. Note that I also commented out the boxplot that reads from IT'S OWN table. My usage has one inline table and several plot types. I searched the manual with no success.
Thank you in advance for any help. Dave

Comment: Works fine here, when I add the missing semicolon at the end of the `\addplot`.

Comment: Much thanks. I used cut and paste in Latex Writer on iPad and it drops characters at the end of line. Its difficult to track things down when the line wrap around the small screen.

Comment: The real problem is the boxplot node labeling which I commented out. Given I read the data putside the addplot boxplot call, how do I get the pgfmathprintnumber access to the boxplot node label data? The example above can draw the boxplot, but it can' print the labels...it just crashes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Too long for a comment.)

Your code seems to work fine, including annotations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics} 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
%\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
miles
1
2
1
5
4
10
7
10
9
8
9
9
%\end{filecontents}
}\mytable

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\mytable}
\edef\numberofrows{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y=1.5cm,ymax=2] 
\addplot+[boxplot] table[ y index=0, row sep=newline ]{\mytable}
node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{lower whisker},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}} 
node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{lower quartile},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{lower quartile}}} 
node[left] at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{median},0.5) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}} 
node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{upper quartile},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper quartile}}} 
node at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{upper whisker},1) {\pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}}; 
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your omission of the [above] text is the key, as well as the scope of the semicolon. Thank you very much for your interest, time and help. Best regards, Dave.